# Many multirows in table

Tags: tables

I am trying to achive something like this

```
    Name | Age | Sex | AverageGrade | Subject | Grade |
---------------------------------------------------------
         |     |     |              |Maths    | A     |
    Jhon | 24  | M   | A            |Science  | A     |
         |     |     |              |Arts     | A     |
---------------------------------------------------------
         |     |     |              |Maths    | A     |
    Mary | 24  | M   | A            |Science  | A     |
         |     |     |              |Arts     | A     |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using `multirow` on each of the first four column. Is there a simpler way to achive this.

Comment: What happens if you just use multirow on the `Subject` column?

Comment: Multirow is used to combined different rows. Therefore, I used it to combine the 3 rows in the first four columns.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Misunderstood your question. I see what you mean now. (BTW, afaik, there's no simpler way.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any one of the following possibilities:

1. spread the cells across rows using [`multirow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow) (as you are already doing);
2. combine the contents of the multi-line cells into a `tabular` of its own; or
3. not use either 1 or 2 above, since you're using an odd number of entries to span your content.

I would go with either option 2 or 3. Here's a minimal example addressing the above 3 possibilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\begin{document}

\noindent Option 1: \par\medskip
\begin{tabular}{rccllc}
  \toprule
  Name & Age & Sex & Average Grade & Subject & Grade \\
  \midrule
  \multirow{3}*{John} & \multirow{3}*{24} & \multirow{3}*{M} & \multirow{3}*{A} &
    Maths & A \\
    &&&&Science & A \\
    &&&&Arts & A \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  \multirow{3}*{Mary} & \multirow{3}*{22} & \multirow{3}*{F} & \multirow{3}*{A} &
    Maths & A \\
    &&&&Science & A \\
    &&&&Arts & A \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\noindent Option 2: \par\medskip
\begin{tabular}{rccllc}
  \toprule
  Name & Age & Sex & Average Grade & Subject & Grade \\
  \midrule
  John & 24 & M & A & 
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Maths \\ Science \\ Arts\end{tabular}& 
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}A \\ A \\ A\end{tabular} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  Mary & 22 & F & A &
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Maths \\ Science \\ Arts\end{tabular}& 
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}A \\ A \\ A\end{tabular} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\noindent Option 3: \par\medskip
\begin{tabular}{rccllc}
  \toprule
  Name & Age & Sex & Average Grade & Subject & Grade \\
  \midrule
       &    &   &   & Maths & A \\
  John & 24 & M & A & Science & A \\
       &    &   &   & Arts  & A \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
       &    &   &   & Maths & A \\
  Mary & 22 & F & A & Science & A \\
       &    &   &   & Arts  & A \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I've used [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for the presentation.

Answer (score 5):

use a `m`-column specifier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rccl m{1.25cm} c@{}}  \toprule
  Name & Age & Sex & Average Grade & Subject & Grade \\  \midrule
  John &  24 & M & A & Maths \newline Science\newline Arts & A \\[\medskipamount]
  Mary &  22 & F & A & Maths \newline Science\newline Arts & A \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]